# How can we retrieve data from datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can we retrieve data from datastore where we want to use one element of list property as parameter in google app engine?

Comment: +1.  It's in the docs, but it's certainly hard to find.

Answer (score 3):

If I read you correctly: you need to retrieve the whole element containing that particular list property (with either a `qgl` query or explicit filtering), then access on that element the attribute name of that property.

For an alternate reading: if you want an element whose list property in question contains a certain value, as for that attribute to "equal" said value.  As [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ListProperty) say:

> In a query, comparing a list property
>   to a value performs the test against
>   the list members: `list_property =
>   value` tests if the value appears
>   anywhere in the list

Did you mean one of these two things, or yet another I wasn't able to guess from your arcane words?-)